# Reading multiple Excel files with Dask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

Can someone help me understand how to read multiple excel files in Dask?
In Pandas, I would use Glob and do this

```
files = glob.glob('Working Files/*.xlsx')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(i, skiprows=2) for i in files], ignore_index=True)
```

**Need help with doing the same in Dask**

Thanks,

Jac

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to wrap your function in a `delayed` API:

```py
import dask

files = glob.glob('Working Files/*.xlsx')

# note we are wrapping in delayed only the function, not the arguments
delayeds = [dask.delayed(pd.read_excel)(i, skiprows=2) for i in files]

# the line below launches actual computations
results = dask.compute(delayeds)

# after computation is over the results object will 
# contain a list of pandas dataframes
df = pd.concat(results, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response; one question:
By doing this pd.concat I will be moving to pandas from Dask, right?
I'm trying to switch to Dask because I read  that Dask is faster, is this method still the optimal way to do it? can I concatenate in Dask itself, won't that be faster?

PS: pardon, if it's a dumb thought :P , I'm fairly new to these

Comment: Depending on your use case, data, etc, it might be faster to keep the data in pandas...

Answer (score 0):

Following the approach, I had some issues with pd.concat, there I changed that creating an array insted of concat.  Hope it works!

```
files = glob.glob(r"D:\XX\XX\XX\XX\XXX\*.xlsx")

# note we are wrapping in delayed only the function, not the arguments
delayeds = [dask.delayed(pd.read_excel)(i, skiprows=0) for i in files]

# the line below launches actual computations
results = dask.compute(delayeds)

# after computation is over the results object will 
# contain a list of pandas dataframes
dask_array = dd.from_delayed(delayeds) # here instead of pd.concat
dask_array.compute().to_csv(r"D:\XX\XX\XX\XX\XXX\*.csv") # Please be aware of the dtypes on your Excel.
```